# numpy.dtype has the wrong size error while installing python software

Tags: python, numpy

I already when through a number of similar thread testing the solutions but I was not able to make it work.

I'm installing a software called poretools for analysis of sequencing data. The installation goes on without problems, and all depoencencies are satisfied. But when I run the software I get the following error:

```
    dg@dg-XPS-13:~$ poretools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/poretools", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('poretools==0.6.0', 'console_scripts', 'poretools')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/poretools/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Fast5File import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/poretools/Fast5File.py", line 6, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
  File "h5py/h5t.pxd", line 14, in init h5py._conv (/tmp/pip_build_root/h5py/h5py/_conv.c:7359)
  File "h5py/numpy.pxd", line 66, in init h5py.h5t (/tmp/pip_build_root/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:20505)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

I already tried to update and reinstall numpy, now at the latest version numpy-1.12.0.

EDIT:
Can try to reproduce using:

```
dg@dg-XPS-13:~$ git clone https://github.com/arq5x/poretools
dg@dg-XPS-13:~$ cd poretools
dg@dg-XPS-13:~/poretools$ sudo python setup.py install
0.6.0
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to poretools.egg-info/requires.txt
writing poretools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to poretools.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to poretools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to poretools.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'poretools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'poretools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/fastq.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/formats.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/version.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/scripts
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/scripts/poretools-script.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/scripts
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/scripts/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/scripts
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/times.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/qual_v_pos.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/index.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/squiggle.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/metadata.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/stats.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/readstats.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/poretools_main.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/combine.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/statistics.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/occupancy.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/organise.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/Fast5File.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/qualdist.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/yield_plot.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/tabular.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/winner.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/nucdist.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/Event.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/events.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/hist.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/poretools/fasta.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/fastq.py to fastq.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/formats.py to formats.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/version.py to version.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/scripts/poretools-script.py to poretools-script.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/scripts/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/times.py to times.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/qual_v_pos.py to qual_v_pos.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/index.py to index.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/squiggle.py to squiggle.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/metadata.py to metadata.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/stats.py to stats.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/readstats.py to readstats.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/poretools_main.py to poretools_main.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/combine.py to combine.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/statistics.py to statistics.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/occupancy.py to occupancy.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/organise.py to organise.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/Fast5File.py to Fast5File.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/qualdist.py to qualdist.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/yield_plot.py to yield_plot.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/tabular.py to tabular.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/winner.py to winner.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/nucdist.py to nucdist.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/Event.py to Event.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/events.py to events.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/hist.py to hist.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poretools/fasta.py to fasta.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying poretools.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying poretools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying poretools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying poretools.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying poretools.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying poretools.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying poretools.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
creating 'dist/poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg
Extracting poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
poretools 0.6.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing poretools script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for poretools==0.6.0
Searching for pandas==0.19.2
Best match: pandas 0.19.2
Adding pandas 0.19.2 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for seaborn==0.7.1
Best match: seaborn 0.7.1
Processing seaborn-0.7.1-py2.7.egg
seaborn 0.7.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/seaborn-0.7.1-py2.7.egg
Searching for matplotlib==2.0.0
Best match: matplotlib 2.0.0
Adding matplotlib 2.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for h5py==2.6.0
Best match: h5py 2.6.0
Adding h5py 2.6.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for numpy==1.12.0
Best match: numpy 1.12.0
Removing numpy 1.8.2 from easy-install.pth file
Adding numpy 1.12.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for pytz==2016.10
Best match: pytz 2016.10
Adding pytz 2016.10 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for python-dateutil==2.6.0
Best match: python-dateutil 2.6.0
Removing python-dateutil 1.5 from easy-install.pth file
Adding python-dateutil 2.6.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for pyparsing==2.1.10
Best match: pyparsing 2.1.10
Removing pyparsing 2.0.1 from easy-install.pth file
Adding pyparsing 2.1.10 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for cycler==0.10.0
Best match: cycler 0.10.0
Adding cycler 0.10.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for subprocess32==3.2.7
Best match: subprocess32 3.2.7
Adding subprocess32 3.2.7 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for functools32==3.2.3.post2
Best match: functools32 3.2.3.post2
Adding functools32 3.2.3.post2 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for six==1.10.0
Best match: six 1.10.0
Adding six 1.10.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Finished processing dependencies for poretools==0.6.0
dg@dg-XPS-13:~/poretools$ poretools --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/poretools", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('poretools==0.6.0', 'console_scripts', 'poretools')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/poretools/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Fast5File import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poretools-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/poretools/Fast5File.py", line 6, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
  File "h5py/h5t.pxd", line 14, in init h5py._conv (/tmp/pip_build_root/h5py/h5py/_conv.c:7359)
  File "h5py/numpy.pxd", line 66, in init h5py.h5t (/tmp/pip_build_root/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:20505)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Requirements:
h5py>=2.2.0
matplotlib
seaborn
pandas

Not sure what else I can do.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It is very difficult for us to help you unless we see the relevant part of your source code. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem in the error message is not with numpy.  It is in h5py.  try reinstalling it.

Comment: I uninstalled h5py and reinstalled it (using pip), but I get the same error.

Comment: @RoryDaulton what other information can i provide to make this meaningful?

Comment: I'm still stuck with this. Any help?